# Recorded video from iPhone rotated 180 degrees on FB, Vimeo, Youtube

Tags: ios, facebook, ffmpeg, rotation, sharing

it's my first question.

My question is this. I developed some app and the app records a video.

The problem is that the recorded video on iPhone looks rotated 180 degrees in FB, Vimeo, Youtube after sharing it. But it appears normally on iMessage, Instagram. I'm using FFmpeg while recording it.

Could you let me know the cause of the problem and the solution on the code?

Comment: You should post some code which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of ffmpeg you have and how it's compiled, one of the following should work...

```
ffmpeg -vfilters "rotate=90" -i input.mov output.mp4
```

...or...

```
ffmpeg -vf "transpose=1" -i input.mov output.mp4
```

Please try this hope it helps!

Comment: `-vf` is an output option so comes after the inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I will try it!! Than you!